# How can I add spacing in file upload button

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-variants

I wanted to add spacing between the `Choose Files` button and the text on right side. How can I do so by tailwind CSS. I had added the code below .

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<section class="body-font text-gray-600">
  <div class="container mx-auto px-5 py-24">
    <div class="mx-auto flex flex-col items-start lg:w-2/3">
      <label class="title-font mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900" for="multiple_files">Upload multiple files</label>
      <input class="w-full cursor-pointer rounded-lg border border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 px-4 py-2 text-lg text-gray-600 file:rounded-lg file:border-none file:bg-indigo-600 file:p-2 file:text-white hover:file:cursor-pointer hover:file:bg-indigo-500" id="multiple_files" type="file" multiple="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `margin-right` to `file`, use this selector `file:mr-4`

```
<input class="file:mr-4" id="multiple_files" type="file" multiple="" />
```

have a look here :
https://play.tailwindcss.com/scMYVnSVjY

Comment: Not working . Please test your approach on tailwind play before posting here.

Comment: @RosePark I posted here after I tested my answer, but have a look I updated my answer.

Comment: it is not showing any spacing in the link you shared

Comment: @RosePark just to make sure that I understood you correctly, you want spacing between the button `Browse...` and the text `No file selected.` right? if so I'm pretty sure it worked, I increased the `mr-4` to `mr-20` it's more obvious now https://play.tailwindcss.com/scMYVnSVjY

Comment: I found that due to my old version of chrome in my laptop it is showing as nothing changed but on checking on my mobile , I saw its working . This is what I want.